# Using PineScript to reassess variable value on each candle to prevent repainting errors

Tags: pine-script

Tradingview's alert options are not ideal for when it triggers on a candle move. This moving average indicator will work until a particular error kicks in, actually somewhat fundamental to coding. Basically since one signal per candle is the condition I have, if the indicator flashes green to red repeatedly during one candle duration, and then settles on the wrong one, there is no 'new' change for the next however many minutes (which means a losing trade because its not getting the new signal)

```
ahma = 0.0
ahma := nz(ahma[1]) + (src - (nz(ahma[1]) + nz(ahma[length])) / 2) / 
length 


col1= ahma>ahma[1]
col3= ahma<ahma[1]
isNewCol1 = nz(col3[1]) and col1
isNewCol3 = nz(col1[1]) and col3
colorP = col1 ? green : col3 ? red : yellow
plot(ahma, color=colorP, linewidth=3, title="ahma")

alertcondition(condition=isNewCol1, title="Long", message="green")
alertcondition(condition=isNewCol3, title="Short", message="red")
```

Ie. it starts off red but the candle closes with the indicator reflashing green, but it can't trigger a new alert and it won't check on the next candle to reassess the value. I.e it's not checking the value. It's not checking to make sure on a new candle open that the value is indeed what it thinks it is, it thinks it's red because the alert didn't allow it to trigger multiple times per candle, which is also a severe repainting error. The best way to avoid all this is to somehow add a couple lines of code to make it recheck the value on the next candle. The reason I don't want to use 'trigger alert on close' is because it triggers orders belatedly, I like the response time of triggering on open, but want it to reassess without firing until the next candle, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Go no-repaint mode from the calcs perspective in your script and accept the fact that in order for that to happen you need to work with data from a bar that has elapsed, in which case your alert can be triggered "Once Per Bar" so it will trigger at the beginning of the bar following confirmation. This will entail modifying your code to reference data from closed bars or the `open` of the realtime bar (which doesn't change).
2. Achieve no-repaint indirectly by keeping your script as is but using "Once Per Bar Close" on your alert.

That's it. There are no other alternatives, as without tick-referencing in Pine, no history of events having occurred during the realtime bar can be preserved before it closes. Variables are only committed on bar close, so they are reinitialized every time your script re-executes in the realtime bar because of a price change.

See here for a discussion on techniques and code to avoid repainting:
https://www.tradingview.com/script/s8kWs84i-How-to-avoid-repainting-when-NOT-using-security/

See here for a description of the runtime model in Pine:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html

Comment: Yes I was reading around and others have had this issue, quite a bit of fuss over it, so you definitely are on point. On a side note I'm considering python to assess study data on a 30 second chart, which would be a good edge in a system, in the grand scheme of things, it seems this lack of feature in pinescript combined with the lack of options on alerts, namely that you can;'t use less than a 1 minute alert are the hangup with TV.

Comment: Well, as TV writes in the User Manual's intro, Pine is a light-weight language. It packs a punch in that it allows traders to do quite a bit with very little code, but it was never intended as an all-encompassing trading platform programming language. So need to figure out what's optimal for your needs and means—which inevitably requires experimentation. Some are happy to do everything in Pine; others use it for prototyping mostly. I think it's definitely found a useful niche of its own, which also implies it's not perfect for everybody. gl!

Comment: Also, until tick-referencing comes to Pine, PineCoders has this suggestion in that would be a function allowing scripts to time the duration of a continuous condition during the realtime bar. Could get us partway there in the meantime: https://trello.com/c/ulHOgJIl

Comment: yes i extensively use time delay with autoview syntax currently, but of course TV has no feature yet. Worse yet the above code I quoted appears to delay not one candle but TWO. On a 2 minute chart, I get a 4 minute delay when on close, and a normal 2 minute delay on once per bar, which of course leads to backwards false signals.